# Visual Studio Code is not installing npm due to core.js

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, npm, npm-install, package.json

I've been trying to install npm but I'm still getting the following error. I'm not sure what the issue is, I tried to re-install core-js but nothing happened. Any help?

[image: error]

Clearing node modules and reinstall. npm is not installing

Comment: Instead of opening a powershell console try with git bash. In the VS console, right next to where it says "powershell" there is a + icon, it allows you to open new consoles, try opening git bash or cmd

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)